# Python, Апроксимировать распределение смесью нормальных распределений

Tags: python

Имеется какое то отличное от нормального распределение плотностей вероятности, задано таблично, 30 точек,иксам ставятся в соответствие вероятности. Необходимо вывести аппроксимирующую это распределение смесь нормальных распределений, то есть получить набор пар мю и сигм в количестве n штук (задает пользователь)

Есть sklearn BayesianGaussianMixture и GaussianMixture, но я не совсем его понял, что туда совать и что выдает fit_predict.

Comment: `fit()` для аппроксимации смеси нормальных распределений на основе табличных данных, `predict()` для предсказания кластера для новых точек после обучения модели. `fit_predict()` не подходит.

Answer (score 1):

Как мне кажется, ваша задача сводиться к задаче Kernel Density Estimation  (русский вариант - ядерная оценка плотности) - аппроксимации заданной функции плотности распределения функциями плотности заданного типа (и гауссовой - как частный случай).

Начать можно вот отсюда:

https://www.mvstat.net/tduong/research/seminars/seminar-2001-05/
https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/density-estimation-mle-map-mom-kde-ecdf-q-q-plot-gan-5161f84d28d7

[https://craftappmobile.com/ядерная-оценка-плотности-распределе/](https://craftappmobile.com/%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5/)
[https://learnmachinelearning.fandom.com/ru/wiki/Ядерное_сглаживание_для_оценки_плотности](https://learnmachinelearning.fandom.com/ru/wiki/%D0%AF%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8)

В Python мне известно четыре реализации (скорее всего есть и другие):

1. В scikit-learn:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity.html#sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity

с официальным описанием:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/density.html#kernel-density

а вот тут -  более развернутое и человеческим языком:

https://stackabuse.com/kernel-density-estimation-in-python-using-scikit-learn/
https://mglerner.github.io/posts/histograms-and-kernel-density-estimation-kde-2.html?p=28
https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/05.13-kernel-density-estimation.html

2.В statsmodels, в которой чуть больше возможностей:

https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/kernel_density.html

3. В scipy.stats.:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html

4. Специализированный пакет KDEpy (честно признаюсь -  эту возможность лично не пробовал):

https://kdepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Пробуйте.